# Why is my site broken when I build it, and ok when I use npm run dev? NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using NextJs, Tailwind, React and Typescript for my project, it's ready, and i need host it. So, i used "output: export" in next.config.js, and i ran npm run build. The process was a success, but when i run my website locally, the images, style with typescript, favicon, and fonts is missing.

I need a static page, and i don't know why my links dont work. Can anyone help?

My next.config.js file:

[image: next.config.js file]

Page run with NextJs:

[image: Page with NextJs]

Page after the build and run with LiveServer:

[image: Page with LiveServer]

Folder Out:

[image: Folder out]

My build make 2 css files:

[image: css files]

The second file is the one that doesn't work very well. I make the connection and this is the result I get:

[image]

Maybe the tailwind is causing this?

Comment: the bottom looks like the CSS isn't loading .. perhaps the location of the CSS file isn't accessable through the web version.  How are you calling the CSS ? Is it embeded, or being called through a CDN or anything like that?

Comment: The build doesn't make the connection between css and html, so I need to put a <link> in the head, although it works in parts, my fonts aren't loaded yet. I think it's because I'm using tailwindcss, I don't know.

Comment: Is the link to a local file you downloaded or to an external file on the web?   If its locally pointing, then the link when you compile it might be pointing to the local physical directory instead of the url/web one, such as D:\web\css\tailwind.css and it needs to point to something like /css/tailwind.css or something like that.

Comment: how are you opening the html? using the vscode live server extension?

Answer (score 0):

You must open your HTML files through a http server that points to the `out` folder. so `localhost/` has to point `out/index.html`

here is how can do it using `http-server` package:

```bash
npx http-server --proxy http://localhost:3000 ./out
```

you can also add it to the `scripts` section in the `package.json` to make it easier to use for later.

or if you are using `live-server` extension in VSCode, you need to open the `out` folder as a workspace and run the live server on it.

**Edit:**
it looks like the default image optimization loader is not yet supported for the app router. you must either use the pages router or use a cloud image storage (e.g. Cloudinary or aws s3)

you can do this by adding a custom loader to your project using this config in the `next.config.js`:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  images: {
    loader: 'custom',
    loaderFile: './my-loader.ts', // you can also use .js
  },
}
```

and then you have to add a logic of how the images must be loaded from your cloud storage:

```js
./my-loader.ts

export default function cloudinaryLoader({
  src,
  width,
  quality,
}: {
  src: string
  width: number
  quality?: number
}) {
  const params = ['f_auto', 'c_limit', `w_${width}`, `q_${quality || 'auto'}`]
  return `https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/${params.join(
    ','
  )}${src}`
}
```

I believe you can add some logic to load the images from the file system and optimize them using the [Sharp.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) library. and of course, you can cache them to use later.

let me know if it is confusing for you or you need more information

Comment: This solved my problem with css, but why my images still don't appear? Do i need to put some command in next.config.js for make the links to work?

Comment: @ArthurdeAraujoNeves just updated the answer :) I hope that helps